# SQL exception Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'And'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am creating a asp web form page, this part is building a query and an exception is thrown when the `boatYear` part is being added. In the database it is a `smallint`.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Query:

```
    string qs = Request.QueryString["dir"].ToString();
    string sql = "Select * From Boats ";
    string boatClass = "";
    string boatYear = "";
    string boatMake = "";
    string boatUsedNew = "";

    if (qs.Equals("f"))
    {
        boatClass = (string)Session["class"];
        boatYear = (string)Session["year"];
        boatMake = (string)Session["make"]; ;
        boatUsedNew = (string)Session["usednew"];
    }

    string where = "";

    if (qs != "b")
    {
        if (boatClass != "all" && boatClass != "")
        {
            where = "Where Class = '" + boatClass + "'";
        }

        if (boatYear != "all" && boatYear != "")
        {
            if (where == "")
            {
                where += "Where ";
            }
            else
            {
                where += " AND ";
            }
            where += "Year = " + boatYear;
        }

        if (boatMake != "all" && boatMake != "")
        {
            if (where == "")
            {
                where += "Where ";
            }
            else
            {
                where += " AND ";
            }
            where += "Make = '" + boatMake + "'";
        }

        if (boatUsedNew != "all" && boatUsedNew != "")
        {
            if (where == "")
            {
                where += "Where ";
            }
            else
            {
                where += " AND ";
            }
            where += "UsedOrNew = '" + boatUsedNew + "'";
        }

        sql += where;
        Session["sql"] = sql;
    }
    else
    {
        sql = (string)Session["sql"];
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to print out your SQL?

Comment: This is very poor practice, its prone to a lot of errors.  Its hard to read...you should simply debug what sql is generated.  Your if conditions are strange.  You know you can use string.IsNullOrEmpty() right?

Comment: Ugh. Why not `WHERE 1=1`, then you can simply add new clauses always using `AND`. This would de-spaghetti your code greatly...

Comment: You might be missing some spaces in the SQL string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, this approach is prone to SQL injection - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection . To protect your code against SQL injection you should use parameterized queries, where you place parameter names instead of direct values in the conditions. Composing the SQL statement can still be done using a list of strings.

```
List<string> conditions = new List<string>();

if (boatClass != "all" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(boatClass))
  conditions.Add("[Class] = @boatClass");
if (boatYear != "all" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(boatYear))
  conditions.Add("[Year] = @boatYear");
if (boatMake != "all" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(boatMake))
  conditions.Add("[Make] = @boatMake");
if (boatUsedNew != "all" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(boatUsedNew))
  conditions.Add("[UsedOrNew] = @boatUsedNew");

if (conditions.Count > 0)
  sql += " where " + string.Join(" AND ", conditions);
```

Then, of course, parameters of correct types should be passed to the code that sets up and runs the command with this SQL.

Comment: I still get the same exception

Comment: Happy SQL Injection party

Comment: @Igor your answer is correct but you should add some warning to the fact that concatenating string in this way is prone to hacks. Then it is up to the poster to explain why he chooses this coding.

Comment: This is a private project, its not going on any server I just need the basics to work first

Comment: @cb01 Stackoverflow answers aren't just for the person asking the question

Comment: Very nice Igor.  I was about to answer the question with almost exactly the  same code.  I would conditionally add the parameters (`cmd.Parameters.Add(...)`) in the if statements as well though.

Comment: @RobertMcKee - I would too. The question code just doesn't show what command is used to run query.

Comment: You might consider adding a mention about the [QuoteName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function if concatenation absolutely must be done in C#. That would eliminate some or all of SQL injection worries.